# Error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Starting with rails and I had a problem with 'rails s' and the following error appears:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8: symbol lookup error: /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta5-x86_64-linux/lib/v8/init.so: undefined symbol: rb_intern2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider updating to the latest version of Ruby and Rails (1.9.2 and 3.2.7, respectively). Also, you should make sure you have the latest version of the gem by running

```
gem uninstall therubyracer
gem install therubyracer
```

Note that servers such as WEBrick need to be restarted after installing gems; you can't just install the gem, include it in your code, and refresh the page like you can with new JS or CSS.

Comment: but the current project i'm its using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.2. how to make work in this version..
I like what you suggested and still the same error.
/usr/bin/ruby1.8: symbol lookup error: /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta5-x86_64-linux/lib/v8/init.so: undefined symbol: rb_intern2

Comment: Thanks if you can help me find a solution thankful right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue but it seems that my local version requires the beta of therubyracer (to support libv8 as it throws a compile error without it on OS X 10.8), but my production system does not (CentOS).

I tried specifying group :production do in my bundle, but it throws an error saying i've called the gem twice. http://gembundler.com/rationale.html was what had me try that.